# isNaN returns false for letters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a textbox:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="1" class="form-control" data-bind="value: number,  valueupdate:'afterkeydown'" required="">
```

It's binded to this `viewModel`:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.number = ko.observable(1);
    }
```

Later in the `viewModel` I have function where I check if value `Number` is really a number and greater than one:

```
if (self.number() < 1 || isNaN(self.number()) {
   console.log(isNaN(self.number());
   alert("Error");
   return true;
}
```

I checked input like:

- A
- a
- asdsfdsfs
- 1

for all of them `isNaN(self.number()) returns false`

What can couse this error?

@Update:
I checked with `console.log(self.number())`
for letters input it returns empty string. So why isNaN returns false instead of true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `input` is of type `number` any value that is not numeric will be interpreted as the empty string.

So you end up with an empty string and then pass it to `isNaN`. What happens then? See [`isNaN`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4) in the spec:

> 1. If ToNumber(*number*) is NaN, return true.
> 2. Otherwise, return false.

So "ToNumber" is called with the empty string. The empty string coerces to `0` when the "ToNumber" operation is applied to it, and `0` is not `NaN`. See [ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3.1) in the spec:

> The MV of *StringNumericLiteral* ::: [empty] is 0.